# Find the equation of the tangent line to $x^2-xy+y-3=0$ when $x=-1$

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, tangent-line

Find the equation of the tangent line to:    $x^2-xy+y-3=0$   at the point   $x=-1$

I've tried to use implicit differentiation to do this, but in the answer I got, if I substitute $x=-1$ into the equation it will be undefined. I'm not sure I've done it right. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can rearrange your equation into something of the form $y = f(x)$. If you do this, then you don't have to use implicit differentiation.

Comment: Kindly include your working in your post if possible so that others can tell what went wrong in your working if there is one.

Comment: Note that $x=-1$ is not a point. A point on the plane should have both an $x$ and a $y$ coordinate. Put simply, the first step is to compute the value of $y$ on the curve that corresponds to $x=-1$.

Comment: Note that $-(-1)y=y$ if that is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x = -1$, we have
$$ (-1)^2 - (-1)y + y - 3 = 1 + y + y - 3 = -2 + 2y = 0
\implies y = 1.
$$
Thus we are seeking $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ when $(x,y) = (-1,1)$.  Via implicit differentiation, we obtain
\begin{align}
x^2 - xy + y - 3 = 0 &\implies 2x - \left( x\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + y\right) + \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0 \\
&\implies 2x - x\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} - y + \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = 0 \\
&\implies (1-x)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = y-2x \\
&\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{y-2x}{1-x}.\tag{$\ast$}
\end{align}
Substituting the point $(x,y) = (-1,1)$ into ($\ast$), we conclude that
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1-2(-1)}{1-(-1)} = \frac{1+2}{1+1} = \frac{3}{2}. $$
This gives the slope of the tangent line.  To obtain the equation for the tangent line, remember that a line with slope $m$ passing through a point $(x_0,y_0)$ has equation
$$ y-y_0 = m(x-x_0).$$
Therefore an equation for the line tangent to the given curve through the point $(-1,1)$ is given by
$$y - 1 = \frac{3}{2} (x+1). $$

Comment: Xander Henderson, that is the answer I got. But is that the equation of the tangent line?

Comment: That is the slope of the tangent line.

Comment: How can I use that to get my tangent equation?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give the tangent line.

Comment: So that's what the textbook was trying to tell me! My textbook doesn't always explain in detail. Thank you so much for you help. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to implicit differentiation, $$ x^2 - xy + y - 3 = 0 $$ could be rearranged as $$ y = \frac{3-x^2}{1-x}$$ (for $x \neq 1)$  , the derivative of which equals $$ \frac{x^2 - 2x +3}{(1-x)^2} $$
The derivative evaluated at $x=-1$ equals $\frac{3}{2} $.
Also, one verifies that for $x=-1$, $y=1$.

So the equation for the tangent line equals $$ y - 1 = \frac{3}{2} (x+1) $$

Comment: Thank you, An aedonist!

Comment: My pleasure L Hunt, all the best

Answer (score 0):

This is purely algebraic:

As  the point with abscissa $-1$ is $(-1,1=$, set $X=x+1$, $Y=y-1$ (i.e. change origin) and rewrite the equation with $X$ and $Y$. You obtain
$$X^2-XY-3X+2Y=0.$$
The equation at tangent at origin is the *linear part* of this equation:
$$-3X+2Y=0\iff 3x-2y+5=0.$$